# sequence convergence through subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the sequence $(a_n)=n\sin((n\pi)/2)$ and i have to check if this is a convergent one or not.
Well i started by taking the subsequence $a_{2n}$ which converges to $0$ but I cannot find an other subsequence to end my task since if i take either $a_{3n}$ or $a_{2n+1}$ which i believe converge to something other than $0$ I am unable to calculate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):a_{4n+1}=4n+1$

Comment: but how exactly do i calculate $sin(pi(4*n+1)/2)$

Comment: You have $\sin\left(\pi\frac{4n+1}2\right)=\sin\left(2\pi n+\frac\pi2\right)=\sin\left(\frac\pi2\right)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**-$\sin (n\pi/2)=\pm 1$ for $n=4k\pm 1, k\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$